# Create and join a piece to a user (of a particular group) upon user creation in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

The site I'm building contains user `profiles` that I've set up as `pieces` that `joinByOne` to a `user`. Right now, the creation of the profile piece and the join to the user are a manual process but I need to automate that process.

*Upon creation of a user (in a particular group) I need to:*

1. Create a new instance of a profile piece
2. Assign that piece to the newly created user
3. Redirect that user to an edit form view of their profile piece (which should also occur upon subsequent successful logins of the user)

*Upon trash of a user of this privileged group I need to:*

1. Trash any associated profile piece

*Upon rescue from trash of a user of this privileged group I need to:*

1. Rescue any associated profile piece from the trash

---

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an `afterInsert` method for your project level `lib/modules/apostrophe-users`, in which you insert a profile piece by invoking the `insert` API of your profiles module.

To create a join between them, I'd suggest a `joinByOne` relationship from the profile back to the user. If the join field is called `_user` and `idField` is set to `userId`, then you can preset this relationship by setting the `userId` property to the `_id` of the user when you maker the `insert` call.

As for the trash, users have `afterTrash` and `afterRescue` methods waiting for you to override them.

[This HOWTO contains more details about how to work with the model layer.](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/model-layer.html)